# How to make sure an ID is passed in a redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes

A 'Challenges' show.html.erb page lists all Puns for that Challenge and under each Pun I render all that Pun's Comments. Under a pun is an Add Comment button.

That Add Comment form page has the url:

```
http://localhost:4000/puns/109/comments/new?challenge_id=22&user_id=2
```

So I can see the challenge_id is being used

My problem is after I submit a comment (which is successfully posted), I cannot work out how to redirect to the Challenge show page.

```
def create
user_id = current_user.id if current_user
respond_to do |format|
    if @pun.comments.create!(comment_params.merge(user_id: user_id, pun_id: @pun.user_id))
      format.html { redirect_to @challenge }
    else
      format.html { render :new, notice: 'Comment not saved. Something went wrong.' }
      format.json { render json: @challenge.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The error I get is

```
ActionController::ActionControllerError in CommentsController#create
Cannot redirect to nil!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out. I wasn't giving the ID of the Challenge to the path.

Answer:

```
redirect_to challenge_path(@pun.challenge_id)
```